# How to solve this optimization problem efficiently?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let, $D\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times M}$ is a row vector with $M$ elements

$V\in\mathbb{C}^{3^M\times M}$ is a given matrix

$T$ is a scalar (real and $>1$)

$\textbf{The problem at hand is as follows:}$

$$\min_{Y}||D-S||_1$$

Comment: I don't know what happened with the edits, but the current version is completely unreadable. What are $S$ and $Y$? Why are $V$ and $T$ defined but not uesd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model this as an integer quadratic program. Let $x_i$ be a nonnegative integer variable indicating the number of times index $i$ is selected ($i=1,\dots,2^M$). Rewrite the equation defining $S$ as $$S=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^{2^M} V(i,:)x_i$$and add one more constraint:$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^M} x_i = T.$$

Whether this solves "efficiently" or not is an empirical matter. Given that the number of integer variables is exponential in $M$, I would expect the problem to become intractable for all but the very small values of $M$.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Yes, I can solve my problem, but for large value of M, the solver runs very slow. Can you suggest some relaxation technique for higher values of M. For M upto 11, its fine, but beyond that the solver has some problem.